# How Do I Perform a DotNetNuke WebAPI Update/Delete?

Tags: api, controller, dotnetnuke

I've got a dnn module that I've created that has no problem retrieving data from the server using the WebAPI. However, when I try to perform an update, I continue to get errors no matter what I try. Viewing in Firebug, I can the data being posted:

!(http://www.virtual-essentials.com/personal/firebug1.png)

But, when I debug, I see nothing but default (null.setnull) values (bool = false, int = 0, string= empty).

Then, of course the response is no good and results in this:
!(http://www.virtual-essentials.com/personal/firebug2.png)

I've tried every combination of things I can think of, but cannot get this figured out and I'm going nuts.

Here is the ajax call:
    //U//operation - update
    self.updateTestimonial = function (objItem) {
        var method = "UpdateTestimonial";
        self.UpdatePublishStatus(objItem);

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: sf.getServiceRoot('VirtualEssentials/Testimonials') + "TestimonialWeb/" + method,
        beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeaders,
        data: ko.toJSON({ item: new TestimonialInfoDTO(objItem.TestimonialID(), objItem.IsPublished())}),
        success: function (data) {
            self.userAlertText(objItem.Testimonial() + ' changes have been saved');
            //self.getTestimonials(); //get the new data after updates
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            self.userAlertText('OOPS! Error updating ' + objItem.Testimonial + '<br />' + (error));
            //put the status back
            self.UpdatePublishStatus(objItem);

        }
    });
};
```

Here is the WebAPI Controller call:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Edit)]
    public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage UpdateTestimonial(TestimonialInfoDTO item)
    {
        try
        {
            Controller.TestimonialController objController = new Controller.TestimonialController();
            objController.PublishTestimonial(item.TestimonialID, item.IsPublished);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException ex)
        {
            return ex.Response;
        }

    }
```

Any help on this is sincerely appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

It never fails that you find a solution as soon as you ask for help. I pulled the source code for the core Journal module and saw that they were posting the post data a bit differently. I modified the json string that I was sending and it all went through. I thought since the parameter for the method was:

```
 UpdateTestimonial(TestimonialInfoDTO item)
```

that it was expecting:

```
 {"item":{"TestimonialID":14,"IsPublished":false}}
```

but, it turns out what it really wants is:

```
{"TestimonialID":14,"IsPublished":false}
```

Anyhow, here is what I did to make the changes; I just changed the way I built the data to post.

```
    var data = new TestimonialInfoDTO(objItem.TestimonialID(), objItem.IsPublished());

    $.ajax({
   ...
    data: ko.toJSON(data),
```

I hope this helps someone. There isn't a lot of Dnn WebAPI documentation out at this point.

Thanks!
Briana